# group items in array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of items, can be objects with many properties, and I want to group some of these items based on order:

example:

```
[a,b,c,d,e] => [a,[b,c,d],e]
must group (b, c, d)  or (a) or (b, c) or (all)

must not group (a, c) or (a, d) for example because they are not sequential 

Some possibilites:

   [a,b,c,d]   to   [[a,b,c,d]]
   [a,b,c,d]   to   [[a],b,c,d]
   [a,b,c,d]   to   [[a,b],c,d]
   [a,b,c,d]   to   [[a,b,c],d]
   [a,b,c,d]   to   [a,b,[c,d]]

always sequential items
think of item a like an object with index;
```

Comment: please add some more examples and some code you tried.

Comment: why has `[a,b,,c,d]` four possibilities?

Comment: typo sorry first time using the site

Comment: why not for `[a,b,c,d]`: `[a[b,c,d]]`?

Comment: yes   thinks of it like selection

Comment: Should the start index of the grouping and the number of items be random or is there a criteria for that?

Comment: yes : start and end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to group `n` sequential elements of the array starting from an index `ind` and put that that group back into the array at the same index. You can acheive that using `splice`:

```js
function group(arr, ind, n) {
  var g = arr.splice(ind, n);      // cut out n elements from the array at index ind
  arr.splice(ind, 0, g);           // push back those cut-out elements into the same index ind (the elements are in array because of the first slpice call)
}


var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

group(arr, 2, 3);

console.log(arr); // [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6]
```

**EDIT:**

As requested, changing `group` to create a new array instead of altering the original and taking `start` and `end` indexes. So for that we are going to use `slice`/`concat` instead of `splice`:

```js
function group(arr, start, end) {
  return [].concat(arr.slice(0, start), [arr.slice(start, end + 1)], arr.slice(end + 1));
}


var arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];

console.log(group(arr, 2, 3)); // => [1, 2, [3, 4, 5], 6]
console.log(group(arr, 4, 6)); // => [1, 2, 3, 4, [5, 6]]
console.log(group(arr, 0, 3)); // => [[1, 2, 3, 4], 5, 6]
```

which concatinate the subarrays: from `0` to `start`, from `start` to `end + 1` (put in an array of its own so its stays grouped) and from `end + 1` onward. If you want the `end` index to be exclusive (the element at `end` not included) then just change `end + 1` to `end`.

Comment: good job, can you make it work with indexes : start ,end 
and not change the original array? Thanks.

Comment: That's exactly what I need.Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the more recent comments you may be looking for [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)'s own, built-in [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) method, it provides a continuous sub-region of an array, where start and end positions are its arguments:

```js
function format(a){return "["+a.join(",")+"]";}

var arr=['a','b','c','d','e'];
console.log("original: "+format(arr));
console.log("slice(0,1): "+format(arr.slice(0,1)));
console.log("slice(0,2): "+format(arr.slice(0,2)));
console.log("slice(1,4): "+format(arr.slice(1,4)));
console.log("slice(2,4): "+format(arr.slice(2,4)));
console.log("slice(2,2): "+format(arr.slice(2,2)));
```

Note 1: The second argument is the position of the "last+1" element you want, it is best seen in the last example where `slice(2,2)` provides an empty array
Note 2: `format` is just about getting array contents in one line, `console.log(somearray)` displays the elements vertically.

Then of course you can do whatever you need, but it is definitely worth to note that this function exists and it is built-in.
Like building the array-in-array thing you describe:

```js
function format(a){var s="[",first=true;a.forEach(function(i){
  if(first)first=false;else s+=",";s+=i instanceof Array?format(i):i;});
  s+="]";return s;}

function group(arr,begin,end){
  var ret=[];
  for(var i=0;i<begin;i++)ret.push(arr[i]);
  ret.push(arr.slice(begin,end));
  for(var i=end;i<arr.length;i++)ret.push(arr[i]);
  return ret;
}

var arr=['a','b','c','d','e'];
console.log("original: "+format(arr));
console.log("group(arr,0,1): "+format(group(arr,0,1)));
console.log("group(arr,0,2): "+format(group(arr,0,2)));
console.log("group(arr,1,4): "+format(group(arr,1,4)));
console.log("group(arr,2,4): "+format(group(arr,2,4)));
console.log("group(arr,2,2): "+format(group(arr,2,2)));
```

Examples are the same as for the `slice`-explanation, including the empty array in the last one (with 2,2). It is up to you if you want such empty element (as kind of a 'cursor') or not.

And of course the thing also works with the nested loops in my original answer, if you want to generate all possible selections from an array - that is how your question initially seemed to me:

```js
function format(a){var s="[",first=true;a.forEach(function(i){
  if(first)first=false;else s+=",";s+=i instanceof Array?format(i):i;});
  s+="]";return s;}

function group(arr,begin,end){
  var ret=[];
  for(var i=0;i<begin;i++)ret.push(arr[i]);
  ret.push(arr.slice(begin,end));
  for(var i=end;i<arr.length;i++)ret.push(arr[i]);
  return ret;
}

var arr=['a','b','c','d','e'];
console.log("original: "+format(arr));
for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
  for(var j=i+1;j<=arr.length;j++){
    console.log(format(group(arr,i,j)));
  }
```

Comment: Thanks.I just need a simple solution